# how can I manually update some table values in an Excel data model table imported from csv with power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Excel power query to import csv files containing transactions from a directory. That way adding a new file to the directory automatically makes it available when refreshing the query/data model. I load the table from the csv files into the data model. I do some cleaning and data transformation in the query.

However, there are some things that I can't do in the query that loads the raw data.

- There may be missing data that I need to enter manually (a column missing some values)
- I may need to split a transaction/row into multiple transactions/rows to categorize the parts correctly

It seems like there should be a way to do this that allows me to make my changes and not have them overwritten when I refresh the query to import new transactions.

Currently I am experimenting with creating a column with a unique id for the transaction table as part of the query. Then creating an aux table in excel relating to the raw transactions by unique id. I then make my changes in the aux table. And finally, I create a new table that merges the raw transactions with the aux table to create the working transaction table. This does work for missing data, or incorrect values, but it still doesn't allow me to split a row into multiple rows.

I would welcome any suggestions or references.

Comment: wish I had $1 for each time I posted this in answer to same qustion ... see self referencing tables at https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I read your article. It is very similar to the method I am using currently, with the exception that I am creating a new table and you merge comments back into the original table. I had already solved the unique id problem by creating a calculated column that concatenates enough column values to be unique. Do you have any suggestions for splitting rows?

Comment: I'm not Matt ... but beyond that, you haven't provided any sample before after data for me to understand what you are looking for beyond that, and what code you have already developed

Comment: Regarding suggestions for splitting a row into multiple rows, does this post help ? https://superuser.com/a/1602762